# Help Generating Example Data for a Specified Correlation

Tags: correlation, simulation

I would like to generate example data based on the following information:

Group 1: Mean = 93.6, SD = 10.9
Group 2: Mean = 40.2, SD = 5.6

The correlation between these groups is known to be .72.

Is there a way I can randomly generate 20 example cases that would conform to this data?  Is this possible to do in SPSS, Excel, or another relatively basic software package?  I have seen similiar questions posted, but all of the answers referred to the r statistics package, which I have no experience with.

Comment: What you're asking isn't "relatively basic", which is why you don't see answers saying how to do it in those packages. Most likely if you want to do it in SPSS or Excel, & w/o a lot of programming, it can't be done. Do you want to generate sample data from a population w/ those parameters, or do the sample statistics have to exactly equal those values?

Comment: Great opportunity to learn R. It will make all your subsequent encounter with data more fun!

Comment: Gung- thank you for your response. I am just looking to generate sample data from a population with these parameters; the data do not have to conform exactly to those values.  Would that simplify the process at all?

Comment: Do you know something about the joint distribution, for example, are you willing to assume a bivariate normal model?